# Javascript pass the String to Java meet null

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I use the webview in Android to build the interface between Java and JavaScript in Perl, at the beginning everything runs well, however suddenly the javascript can just pass INT to Java, the String could not be identified by Java. (SHOWS ""), however, I alert the value and its type shows well. And I could not find any document in the website. Here is the code:

```
     function init()                                     
     {   
        var ans = "$result"; 
        var ss =  document.getElementById("aaa").innerText;
        alert(ss);                                                                                                                   
        window.text.LogResult(ans,ss);                              
     }
```

and in Java:

```
     public void LogResult(int ans, String ss)
    {....}
```

I could get ans correct but ss shows "";

In the second website String pass very well (all strings);

But in the third website, all String cannot pass agagin. (Copy the whole file and edit, so might not be the page format problem ).

Is there anyone knows why? Thank you.